# Get Usernames from String in C

Tags: c, string, char

I am writing a function that is supposed to get an array with a tweet inside it and an empty array which should be filled with usernames that are in the tweet starting with '@' each in its own line. The usernames in the username array should be without the '@'.

This is what I have so far, but this version only stores one username and doesn't even put a new line behind it, and I don't know why.

It's probably a logic mistake?

```
void extract_username(char *tweet, char *user){

    int j = 0;
    int z = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(tweet); i++){
        if(tweet[i] == '@'){
            z = i+1;
            while(tweet[z] != ' '){
                user[j] = tweet[z];
                z++;
                j++;
            }
            j++;
            user[j] = '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

extract_username gets called in the main like this

```
int main(){
    char tweet[281];
    char user[281]; //for example @user1 hello @user2
    
    printf("Please enter a tweet (max. 280 symbols): \n");
    fgets(tweet, 281, stdin);

    extract_usename(tweet, user);

    printf("%s", user);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(tweet[z] != ' '){  user[j] = tweet[z];  z++;  j++;  }` may iterate past the string's _null character_ - bad.  Did you want `tweet[z] != '\0'`?

Comment: Let's see the `tweet` string.  Also, aren't you worried about running past the end of the `tweet` string? Presumably it's NUL terminated, not space-terminated.   Also, how are you ensuring the `user` string gets NUL terminated?

Comment: The `j++` after the `while` loop needs to be *after* `user[j] = '\n';`

Comment: [Edit] and show how you call `extract_username`. Show a [mcve]

Comment: @Wyck the tweet string gets scanned from the keyboard via fgets (for example '@user1' hello '@user2'). I thought I would not run past the end of the tweet because the for loop iterates until strlen(tweet). I guess I should add a '\0' at the end for the user array.

Comment: `while(tweet[z] != ' ')` will happily run past the terminating NUL because `0 != ' '`

Comment: @Wyck Right I should change it to while(tweet[z] != ' ' && tweet[z] != '\0')

Comment: You'd do well to use your debugger to step through this with a known input string and inspect your variables as you go.  You're in for a few surprises and you'll come out a little wiser.

Comment: You aren't null-terminating the result string. You don't have any visible protection against overflows on the string of usernames.  Presumably, this would not be too serious if the user name array is about as long as the tweet string (and tweets are short), but the assumptions made are liable to be subverted by future changes, so be cautious! Would it be better if you return the number of users found?  (I see that a recent update has added the definition of the string to hold users — you are safe enough while the sizes of the tweet and the user strings are the same size.)

Comment: by the way if the tweet is just a string of @s then this will overflow the buffer `user`

Comment: Maybe use `tweet[z] && !isspace(tweet[z])`; there are several spaces, (\t\n\v\f\r and ' '.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the fewest changes possible, change the condition to `while (tweet[z] != ' ' && tweet[z] != 0)` and add the newline with `user[j++] = '\n';`  Probably best to explicitly add the NUL terminator at the end with `user[j] = 0;` as well.

```
void extract_username(char* tweet, char* user) {

    int j = 0;
    int z = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(tweet); i++) {
        if (tweet[i] == '@') {
            z = i + 1;
            while (tweet[z] != ' ' && tweet[z] != 0) {
                user[j] = tweet[z];
                z++;
                j++;
            }
            user[j++] = '\n';
        }
    }
    user[j] = 0;
}
```